# How to add a signing key for modules in OpenSUSE Leap 15?

Tags: kernel-modules, opensuse, signature

Well, I thought I could use openSUSE Leap 15.5 "out of the box" (in my case: after upgrading from 15.4), but I have the problem that a kernel module (WLAN driver) is not accepted by the kernel.

The whole story can be found at [Shouldn't rtl8812au-kmp-default use a signed module?](https://bugzilla.suse.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1214005), and the [relevant comment](https://bugzilla.suse.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1214005#c7) reads:

> It's the nature of Leap; it takes the packages from SLE as-is, and the kernel
> is part of it.  The kernel package is built with SLE cert key, not with
> openSUSE cert.  Meanwhile such a 3rd party KMP is built only for Leap, hence
> it's signed with openSUSE cert key.

So I need some help how to get the correct signing key ("openSUSE cert") into the kernel.